# Oracle - merge multiple rows into one, use column values as row names, dynamic

Tags: oracle, dynamic, pivot

I am trying to merge several rows into one row. The column values need to become the column names, and it needs to be dynamic as there could be more column values added

Current

```
key attribute   value   reason  message             
1001    Att1    Val1    Reason 1    Message 1               
1001    Att2    Val2    Reason 1    Message 1               
1001    Att3    Val3    Reason 1    Message 1               
1002    Att1    Val4    Reason 2    Message 2               
1002    Att2    Val5    Reason 2    Message 2               
1002    Att4    Val7    Reason 2    Message 2               
1002    Att5    Val8    Reason 2    Message 2               
1002    Att6    Val9    Reason 2    Message 2
```

Want this structure

```
key     Att1    Att2    Att3    Att4    Att5    Att6    reason      message
1001    Val1    Val2    Val3                            Reason 1    Message 1
1002    Val4    Val5            Val7    Val8    Val9    Reason 2    Message 2
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

To obtain your result you need a PIVOT operation; the main problem is that you need it to be dynamic, so we don't know in advance the number or columns that you will get.

You can try with some dynamic SQL, building a statement that will match your data:

```
declare
    vSQL varchar2(32767) :=
                            ' from (select * from test)
                              pivot (max(value) for attribute in (';
    vAttributes varchar2(32767);
    vOutputFields varchar2(32767) := 'key || '' | '' || reason || '' | '' || message || '' | '' || ';
    vAllFields varchar2(3) := '*';
    vClob clob;
    type tabVarchar2 is table of varchar2(32767);
    vTabVarchar2 tabVarchar2;
    vSQLOneField varchar2(32767);
    vSQLMoreFields varchar2(32767);
begin
    -- get the columns
    select listagg( '''' || attribute || '''', ',') within group (order by attribute),
     vOutputFields || listagg( '"''' || attribute || '''"', '|| '' | '' || ') within group (order by attribute)
    into vAttributes, vOutputFields
    from (select distinct attribute from test) ;

    -- build the statement for many fields
    vSQLMoreFields := 'select ' || vAllFields || vSQL || vAttributes || '))';
    -- print the query
    dbms_output.put_line(vSQLMoreFields);
    -- fetch it as a unique XML
    select DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML(vSQLMoreFields)
    into vClob
    from dual;   
    dbms_output.put_line(vClob);

    -- build the statement for a unique field
    vSQLOneField := 'select ' || vOutputFields || ' from (' || vSQLMoreFields || ')';
    -- print the query
    dbms_output.put_line(vSQLOneField);
    -- fetch as a unique field into a structure
    execute immediate vSQLOneField bulk collect into vTabVarchar2;
    for i in 1 .. vTabVarchar2.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line( vTabVarchar2(i));
    end loop;

end;
```

I mainly see two problems in this:

- it's hard to find a way to fecth the result and use it; I made the example fetching in into a unique XML, with separated fields, or into an array of `varchar2`, with each value containing the entire row;
- I make access to the table twice, once to get the columns and once to get the real data, and this can be a performance issue

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TransposeTab RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    sqlstr VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
    sqlstr := 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1 PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR ATTRIBUTE IN (';
    FOR aCol IN (SELECT DISTINCT ATTRIBUTE FROM TABLE1) LOOP
        sqlstr := sqlstr || ''''||aCol.ATTRIBUTE||''' AS "'||aCol.ATTRIBUTE||'",';
    END LOOP;
    sqlstr := REGEXP_REPLACE(sqlstr, ',$','))');
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( sqlstr );
    OPEN cur FOR sqlstr;
    RETURN cur;
END;
```

In order to get the result, you can do this one.

```
SELECT TransposeTab FROM dual;
```

or (only in SQL*Plus)

```
var rc refcursor
EXEC :rc := TransposeTab;
PRINT rc
```